# Relationship between access file table and sql server table

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

This code reads table info from an Access file (.mdb) and copies table info to a sql server table.
This code copies `field1` in the Access file to `field1` in the sql server table and copies `field2` to `field2` and ...
this code work correctly but I want change copy.
I want to copy `name` field from the Access file to `nameperson` field in the sql server table.
For example copy `field1` in access to `field5` in sql server table.
How do I do this?

```
 OpenFileDialog openfiledialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
     openfiledialog1.Title = "select path access file";

        openfiledialog1.Filter = "Access 2003 (*.mdb)|*.mdb";
        if (openfiledialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + openfiledialog1.FileName;
            const string connectionStringDest = @"server=ahmad-pc\anfd;database = phonebook;Integrated Security = true";
            using (var sourceConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                sourceConnection.Open();

                var commandSourceData = new OleDbCommand("SELECT id , name , family from numberperson", sourceConnection);
                var reader = commandSourceData.ExecuteReader();

                using (var destinationConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringDest))
                {
                    destinationConnection.Open();

                    using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
                    {
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "profile2";

                        try
                        {
                            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            reader.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                MessageBox.Show("copy successully");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below example, I added one mapping for you converting column name to nameperson

```
[...]
using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
{             
 bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("name", "nameperson"); //THIS A MAPPING REPLACE IT WITH YOUR NEED
 bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "profile2";
[....]
```

Comment: thanks. now copy name field to nameperson field in sqlserver.